# trouble with "if" condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Index view where a person enters a two players and a score and my app is supposed to return the winner of the two. I get the input through the params hash and try to process it but the it seems the first condition supplied in the if always evaluates to true. Below is the code in my from my controller action, plus the view that renders the response:

```
def find_winner
    @player_1 = params[:player_1]
    @player_2 = params[:player_2]
    @set_1 = params[:set_1]
    @set_2 = params[:set_2]
    @set_3 = params[:set_3]

      a = @set_1[0].to_i
      b = @set_1[1].to_i
      c = @set_2[0].to_i
      d = @set_2[1].to_i
      e = @set_3[0].to_i
      f = @set_3[1].to_i

      if ((a + c + e) > (b + d + f)) then 
        @winner = @player_1
      elsif ((a + c + e) < (b + d + f)) then 
        @winner = @player_2
      else
        @winner = "winner"
      end
  end
```

and the code from the .erb template:

```
<%= @player_1 %>
<%= @a %>
<%= @player_2 %>
<%= @set_1.class %>
<%= @set_2 %>
<%= @set_3 %>
<%= @b %>
<blockquote> the winner is <%= @winner %>
```

@winner always evaluates to player_1

Comment: BTW, you don't need `then` keywords here. You may safely drop them.

Comment: I suggest there is a problem with your data. That is, you never send parameters with which a second player should win. Your code looks ok to me.

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SJ1s58B0js+Tbb2LOJ99stlWSUQEk4tLmI3VxzUboYI=", "player_1"=>"loser", "player_2"=>"winner", "set_1"=>"3,6", "set_2"=>"2,6", "set_3"=>"0,0", "commit"=>"get winner"}  
the server sends the above over in the request body. and when i evaluate them like you see in the .erb code they contain values.

Comment: Well, have you tried debug printing actual values of your `a, b, c, d...` vars?

Comment: yes, they all produce integers like i expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, in the end, the problem **is** with your code. Your code does not correspond to the data format. In the comments you show sample data you send. Look:

```
set_1 = '3,6'

a = set_1[0].to_i # => 3
b = set_1[1].to_i # => 0
```

`set_1` here is a string, not the array, as you might think. So, its second element is a comma. And casting comma to integer produces 0. Therefore, sum of (a, c, e) will always be larger than sum of zeroes (b, d, f).

You might want to do something like this instead:

```
a, b = params[:set_1].split(',').map(&:to_i)
c, d = params[:set_2].split(',').map(&:to_i)
e, f = params[:set_3].split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: People would not run into problems like this if they just learned to debug their code. A simple `logger.debug(a,b,c,d,e,f)` would have revealed this problem long ago: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: @Casper: agreed. Some people just can't debug :)

Comment: thanks a gazillion @SergioTulentsev , for some reason i wasn't seeing the comma. I guess sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes. thanks again. :)